# How to force server side serving of a route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-starter-kit

I'm using passport-js with react-starter-kit and universal router, and there are some /login routes that are handled server side.  Is there any way to force a server side fetch from a route url rather than a client-side one?

For instance, if I go to /logout directly from the url - it triggers the correct server side logout.  However, if I click on a /logout link on the browser from the client-side I get a page not found error because it's doing the client-side routing and /logout is not defined in routes.  Is it possible to define a route object that has to get served directly from the server?

routes/index.js

```
export default {

  path: '/',

  // Keep in mind, routes are evaluated in order
  children: [
    require('./home').default,
    require('./contact').default,
    require('./register').default,
    require('./termsOfUse').default,
    require('./privacyPolicy').default,
    require('./invites').default,
    require('./collection').default,
    require('./profile').default,
    require('./content').default,
    require('./notFound').default,
    // Wildcard routes, e.g. { path: '*', ... } (must go last)
  ],

  async action({ next }) {
    // Execute each child route until one of them return the result
    const route = await next();

    // Provide default values for title, description etc.
    route.title = `${route.title}`;
    route.description = route.description || '';

    return route;
  },

};
```

client.js

```
sync function onLocationChange(location) {
  // my workaround is to put a special case for login and logout
  // but it feels a bit of a hack since this logic should be set in the routing
  // config if possible
  if (location.pathname === '/login' || location.pathname === '/logout') {
    // break - let passport.js handle it via server-side
    window.location.reload();
    return;
  }

  ...
  currentLocation = location;

  try {
    // Traverses the list of routes in the order they are defined until
    // it finds the first route that matches provided URL path string
    // and whose action method returns anything other than `undefined`.
    const route = await UniversalRouter.resolve(routes, {
      ...context,
      path: location.pathname,
      query: queryString.parse(location.search),
    });

    // Prevent multiple page renders during the routing process
    if (currentLocation.key !== location.key) {
      return;
    }

    if (route.redirect) {
      history.replace(route.redirect);
      return;
    }

    const component = (
      <App context={context}>
        <ApolloProvider client={context.client} store={context.store}>
          {route.component}
        </ApolloProvider>
      </App>
    );

    appInstance = ReactDOM.render(
      component,
      container,
      () => onRenderComplete(route, location),
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // eslint-disable-line no-console

    // Current url has been changed during navigation process, do nothing
    if (currentLocation.key !== location.key) {
      return;
    }

    // Display the error in full-screen for development mode
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      appInstance = null;
      document.title = `Error: ${error.message}`;
      ReactDOM.render(<ErrorReporter error={error} />, container);
      return;
    }

    // Avoid broken navigation in production mode by a full page reload on error
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to be able to click on a /logout link in client, then redirect to some page, and gets server side responding as well?

Comment: yes I want it to behave as a normal http link rather than an isomorphic client-side routing - I want it to do an explicit page load.  Currently my fix is to go into client.js and do carve out a case for when the route is /login, but not sure if that's the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3109#issuecomment-189782650)

```
<Link to="/someurl" target="_self">...</Link>
```